# MVC Route not working with one set of parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have come across a routing issue which is a bit baffling - my routes are:

```
Public Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()

    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="StrategyDefinitionGet",
        url:="Strategy/Definition/{strategyId}/{resultId}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Strategy", .action = "Definition", .resultId = UrlParameter.Optional},
        constraints:=New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.httpMethod = New HttpMethodConstraint("GET")})
    )

    routes.MapRoute(
        name:="Default",
        url:="{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "Index", .id = UrlParameter.Optional}
    )
End Sub
```

and my Strategy Controller - Definition Action is:

```
<HttpGet, AllowAnonymous> 
Async Function Definition(strategyId As Integer, Optional resultId As Integer? = Nothing) As Task(Of ActionResult)
```

There is a Post version of the action as well (included to explain why I have the GET constraint in the route above):

```
<HttpPost, Authorize, ValidateAntiForgeryToken>
Async Function Definition(strategyModel As StrategyModel) As Task(Of ActionResult)
```

When I go to any link on the site, such as https://investorsedge.net:8443/Strategy/Definition/12898/11583, everything gets routed fine.

When I go to this url https://investorsedge.net:8443/Strategy/Definition/15626/13684, the routing system takes me to Home / Index.

Weirdly, if I remove the optional parameter from the url like this https://investorsedge.net:8443/Strategy/Definition/15626 the system routes me to the correct controller and action with no problems.

Can anyone spot what is going on? I assume its a routing issue, but don't get why it works with every other set of combinations on the site but one.

Comment: Just clicked on all 3 links and none of them went to your Home page

Comment: Your links are all 3 returning `Not Found - Status: NotFound, Reason: Not Found`. Your routing looks okay (except perhaps the `HttpMethodConstraint` you haven't provided), this is likely something else.

Comment: Well that's really strange - after quite a lot of further testing it seems that Firefox, Opera and even IE work correctly. Chrome on my dev machine always routes to Home/Index while Chrome on my iphone routes correctly. Chrome works if I specify a different number for the second parameter, and only fails if the second parameter is 13684! I'm baffled...

Comment: Forgot to say, thanks for checking the issue out